# Write a jstl sql query inside a jquery drop function?

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, jstl

Everytime an element is dropped into a droppable then I want to access the database and output something which I get from their ids.

```
 drop: function(event,ui){
     $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top:0,left:0}).appendTo($(this)); 
     $(ui.draggable).detach().css({top:0,left:0}).appendTo($(this));
     var slotid=$(this).attr("id");
     var courseid=$(ui.draggable).attr("id");
     //Using the above two variables I want to get(and also change) something from(in) the database
 }
```

But inserting the jstl functions here give an error and I couldn't find anything useful from previous such questions to resolve my problem.

Please can someone give some hint on how to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try it with ajax? Which serves your query better.

```
drop: function (event, ui) {                                      
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data: { slotid: $(this).attr("id"), courseid: $(ui.draggable).attr("id");},
        url: 'ServletURL',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
}
```

All you need to do is create separate function for querying the DB with following parameters,

```
String slotid = request.getParameter("slotid");
String courseid = request.getParameter("courseid");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do I need to create a separate page where I update and get values OR Do I need to make a function in the same page (and  how do I make it in same page ) . @Vinoth

Comment: You don't have to create separate page. Use this function in your `droppable` and create a separate servlet to return data from that.